# Restrictions as string to expression in region plots

Tags: plotting, function-construction, string-manipulation

I'm trying to build a function that generate a string of restrictons to pass on to a region plot with ToExpression, but I think it fails to pass the plot variables.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ClearAll[Subscript]
lb1[ps_, pr_] := (Sqrt[1 - ps] + Sqrt[pr - ps])^2/(1 - pr);
lb2[ps_, pr_] := (Sqrt[1 - ps] - Sqrt[pr - ps])^2/(1 - pr);
An[ps_, pr_, bb_,n_] := ((pr - ps)*(1 + lb2[ps, pr]^n) + 2 bb*(1 - lb2[ps, pr]^n))/(2*(pr - ps)*(lb1[ps, pr]^n -lb2[ps, pr]^n));

xp[ps_, pr_, bb_] := 1/2 - bb/(pr - ps);
xn[ps_, pr_, bb_, n_, c_] :=An[ps, pr, bb, n]*(lb1[ps, pr]^c - lb2[ps, pr]^c)+ xp[ps, pr, bb]*(1 - lb2[ps, pr]^c);
sfixed[n_, c_] := FullSimplify[xn[ps, pr, bb, n, c]];
sol[s_, r_, bu_, n_, c_] :=sfixed[n, c] /. {ps -> s, pr -> r, bb -> bu};
ordres[n_] :=Module[{i, x}, x = StringForm["0<sol[s,r,b,``,1]&&", n];Do[x = ToString[x] <>ToString[StringForm["sol[s,r,b,``,``]<sol[s,r,b,``,``]&&", n, i-1, n,i]], {i, 2, n - 1}]; x = ToString[x]<>ToString[StringForm["sol[s,r,b,``,``]<1", n, n - 1]]];
```

The function ordres should generate the restriction for n points. Here I fail to make the plot for n=2.

```
Manipulate[RegionPlot[{ToExpression[ordres[2]]}, {r, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 0.2}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000], {s, 0.8, 1}]
```

This is what I expect to get

```
Manipulate[RegionPlot[{{sol[s, r, b, 2, 1] > 0 && sol[s, r, b, 2, 1] < 1}}, {r,0, 1}, {b, 0, 0.2}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000], {s, 0.8, 1}]
```

Comment: try `Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[ToExpression[ordres[2]] /. s -> t, {r, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 0.2},
   WorkingPrecision -> 1000], {t, 0.8, 1}]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:

````
ordres2[n_, var_] := 
 Module[{i, x}, x = StringForm["0<sol[``,r,b,``,1]&&", var, n]; 
  Do[x = ToString[x] <> ToString[StringForm["sol[``,r,b,``,``]<sol[``,r,b,``,``]&&", var, n, 
       i - 1, var, n, i]], {i, 2, n - 1}]; 
  x = ToString[x] <> ToString[StringForm["sol[``,r,b,``,``]<1", var, n, n - 1]]]

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[ToExpression[ordres2[2, t]], {r, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 0.2}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 1000], {t, 0.8, 1}]
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved by the suggestion of kglr:

```
Manipulate[ RegionPlot[ToExpression[ordres[2]] /. s -> t, {r, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 0.2}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000], {t, 0.8, 1}]
```

Seems to be an issue with manipulate....